# Can these two templates be combined?

Tags: xslt

I have these two XSL templates:

```
  <xsl:template match="OpeningComments">
    <tr>
      <td class="cellTime">
        <xsl:value-of select="Time/@EndTime24"/>
      </td>
      <td class="textTheme">
        <span class="bulletTFGW">&#8226;</span>
        <span class="textTheme">
          <xsl:value-of select="Theme"/>
        </span>
        <span class="textDuration">
          (<xsl:value-of select="Time"/>)
        </span>
      </td>
      <td class="cellName">Chairman</td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ClosingComments">
    <tr>
      <td class="cellTime">
        <xsl:value-of select="Time/@EndTime24"/>
      </td>
      <td class="textTheme">
        <span class="bulletLAC">&#8226;</span>
        <span class="textTheme">
          <xsl:value-of select="Theme"/>
        </span>
        <span class="textDuration">
          (<xsl:value-of select="Time"/>)
        </span>
      </td>
      <td class="cellName">Chairman</td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
```

The only differences are:

1. One is **OpeningComments** and the other **ClosingComments**
2. One uses a class style **bulletTFGW** and the other **bulletLAC**

Can these be sensibly be combined into one template? Or is that going to overcomplicate the task?

Sample XML (cut down):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="WEEK-S-140.xsl"?>
<MeetingWorkBook>
  <Meeting SpecialEvent="0" NumberClasses="1">
    <OpeningComments>
      <Theme>Opening Comments</Theme>
      <Time StartTime12="7:20" StartTime24="19:20" EndTime12="7:23" EndTime24="19:23">3 min.</Time>
    </OpeningComments>

    <LAC CircuitVisit="0">
      <ClosingComments>
        <Theme>Review/Preview/Announcements</Theme>
        <Time StartTime12="8:52" StartTime24="20:52" EndTime12="8:55" EndTime24="20:55">3 min.</Time>
      </ClosingComments>
    </LAC>
  </Meeting>
</MeetingWorkBook>
```

Comment: Could you upload an xml sample as well?

Comment: I have added an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<xsl:template match="OpeningComments | ClosingComments">
    <tr>
        <td class="cellTime">
            <xsl:value-of select="Time/@EndTime24"/>
        </td>
        <td class="textTheme">
            <span>
                <xsl:attribute name="class">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="self::OpeningComments">bulletTFGW</xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>bulletLAC</xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:text>&#8226;</xsl:text>
            </span>
            <span class="textTheme">
                <xsl:value-of select="Theme"/>
            </span>
            <span class="textDuration">
                (<xsl:value-of select="Time"/>)
            </span>
        </td>
        <td class="cellName">Chairman</td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

This is assuming XSLT 1.0.

Comment: Fantastic. Learning a lot with this. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

Yes they can. One clean approach is to use a named template and call it accordingly:

```
<xsl:template name="Comments">
  <xsl:param name="bulletClass" />

  <tr>
    <td class="cellTime">
      <xsl:value-of select="Time/@EndTime24"/>
    </td>
    <td class="textTheme">
      <span class="{ $bulletClass }">&#8226;</span>
      <span class="textTheme">
        <xsl:value-of select="Theme"/>
      </span>
      <span class="textDuration">
        (<xsl:value-of select="Time"/>)
      </span>
    </td>
    <td class="cellName">Chairman</td>
  </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="OpeningComments">
  <xsl:call-template name="Comments">
    <xsl:with-param name="bulletClass">bulletTFGW</xsl:with-param>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ClosingComments">
  <xsl:call-template name="Comments">
    <xsl:with-param name="bulletClass">bulletLAC</xsl:with-param>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
```

Another alternative is to have just one template and select the class based on the current element name:

```
<xsl:template match="OpeningComments | ClosingComments">
  <xsl:param name="bulletClass" />

  <tr>
    <td class="cellTime">
      <xsl:value-of select="Time/@EndTime24"/>
    </td>
    <td class="textTheme">
      <span class="bullet{ concat(
        substring('TFGW', 1, 4 * boolean(self::OpeningComments)),
        substring('LAC' , 1, 3 * boolean(self::ClosingComments))
      ) }">&#8226;</span>
      <span class="textTheme">
        <xsl:value-of select="Theme"/>
      </span>
      <span class="textDuration">
        (<xsl:value-of select="Time"/>)
      </span>
    </td>
    <td class="cellName">Chairman</td>
  </tr>
</xsl:template>
```